# How to create custom admin page with a form in magento2 admin side?

Tags: magento2, adminform

I want to create an admin side custom page with a form, also want to save those fields into a custom table

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom module for this.

You can refer the following links to create the custom module with admin form.
https://webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/

You can also create the admin form using ui Component

https://webkul.com/blog/create-ui-form-magento2-part-1/

https://webkul.com/blog/create-ui-form-magento2-part-2/